# Get Schema error when making Data sync in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

1. I finished setup for the making Azure hub and installing Client Agent and Database .
2. Then define dataset.
   That time whatever database i chose and click get latest schema, got the error.
   Error is

   > The get schema request is either taking a long time or has failed.
3. When check log ,it said like below :

> Getting schema information for the database failed with the exception "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
>   For more information, provide 
>   tracing id ‘xxxx’ to customer support.

Any idea for this?

Comment: How many tables are you trying to sync?

Comment: My DB include more than 900 table.But i will only sync 4 table. I got error when choosing the schema state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current release has maximum of 500 tables in sync group. also, the drop down for the tables list is restricted to this same limit.

here's a quick workaround:

script the tables you want to sync

create a new temporary database and run the script to create the tables you want to sync

register and add the new temporary database as a member of the sync group

use the new temporary database to pick the tables you want to sync

add all other databases that you want to sync with (on-premise databases and hub database)

once the provisioning is done, remove the temporary database from the sync group.

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to perform these steps with current Azure?